# GeoTIFF is solid black after QGIS Python export

Tags: qgis, geoserver

I am trying to automate exporting hundreds of layers from a QGIS project in order to export them into GeoServer. I have a Python script that is exporting the TIFFs successfully but the exported tifs are always black. Any pointers?

Here is the information of the GeoTIFF using gdalinfo

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: m_3208548_se_16_1_20171020_20180102_a.tif
       m_3208548_se_16_1_20171020_20180102_a.tif.aux.xml
Size is 6964, 8236
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World"],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-85.062527050195669,32.312523964278661)
Pixel Size = (0.000008983152841,-0.000007594686085)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -85.0625271,  32.3125240) ( 85d 3'45.10"W, 32d18'45.09"N)
Lower Left  ( -85.0625271,  32.2499741) ( 85d 3'45.10"W, 32d14'59.91"N)
Upper Right ( -84.9999684,  32.3125240) ( 84d59'59.89"W, 32d18'45.09"N)
Lower Right ( -84.9999684,  32.2499741) ( 84d59'59.89"W, 32d14'59.91"N)
Center      ( -85.0312477,  32.2812490) ( 85d 1'52.49"W, 32d16'52.50"N)
Band 1 Block=6964x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Min=0.000 Max=0.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=0.000, Mean=0.000, StdDev=0.000
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Band 2 Block=6964x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Min=0.000 Max=0.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=0.000, Mean=0.000, StdDev=0.000
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Band 3 Block=6964x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Min=0.000 Max=0.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=0.000, Mean=0.000, StdDev=0.000
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Band 4 Block=6964x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=0.000, Mean=0.000, StdDev=0.000
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
```

Here is what I have so far for the python script

```
myDir = 'C:/mydirectory'
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
for layer in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
 print("Converting " + myDir + "/" + layer.name() + '_a.tif') 
 extent = layer.extent()
 width, height = layer.width(), layer.height()
 renderer = layer.renderer()
 provider=layer.dataProvider()

 crsSrc = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(3857)
 crsDest = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)

 xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(crsSrc, crsDest, QgsProject.instance())
 newExtent = xform.transformBoundingBox(extent)

 newExtent.provider.bandScale

 print(newExtent.xMaximum()) 

 pipe.set(provider.clone())
 pipe.set(renderer.clone())

 print(myDir + "/" + layer.name() + '_a.tif') 

 file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(myDir + "/" + layer.name() + '_a.tif')
 file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, width, height, newExtent, crs)
```

I think I know what's happening. It appears that during the automated export my stats on my GeoTIFF are all being set to zero causing the output of the GeoTIFF to be blank. I updated my output using GDAL info above.

The question now is how do I make sure the stats are set during the import?

Comment: Are the pixel values actually 0 or what do you mean by "black"?

Comment: how are you styling the tifs in GeoServer?

Comment: At the moment I am not applying any styling to the images.

Comment: I haven't checked the pixel values to see what they are set too. I am not sure how to look at that at the moment. By black I mean the image is displayed as a black box after the export when as before when I didn't apply any new styling the images looked normal. If I manually export the tif in QGIS using the "Export-> Save As" option the images come at perfect. Right clicking on hundreds of files to do this is a terrible way to do this export that's why I am making the script.

Comment: I am currently missing statistics on my Geotiff would this make a difference?

Comment: Looks like you're exporting each band as a Byte type--is this intentional? What datatype are the rasters originally? [You can check your pixels in QGIS with the Identify Tool.]

Comment: The original data type were j2p. I then used gdal translate to convert them to geotiffs. I want to import the Geotiffs into Geoserver, but Geoserver won't accept the converted Geotiff. I believe it's because the CRS is of a format that Geoserver doesn't like. When I use QGIS I export the Geotiffs with a CRS of EPSG:4326 which makes them work in Geoserver. Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Datatype doesn't refer to the extension of the file (like j2p, geotiff, etc.), it refers to how pixel values are stored on disk. You can  double-click the layer and then choose the "Information" tab. Look for "Data type" and ensure it's the same pre- and post-processed. When you use the Identify Tool and click the pixels of the transformed scenes, do they have values of zero?